# The basics of using strings and substrings in C programming

Tags: c, string, substring

I've been trying to learn C programming by reading a textbook, but am confused about how strings and substrings work.
I have an idea of what strings and substrings are from java, but can't figure out the syntax in C.

Here's a question from the book that I thought might be easy, but I can't get it.

Write and test a function hydroxide that returns a 1 for true if its string argument ends in the substring OH.

It recommends testing the function with KOH and NaCl.

Also, how would I remove and add letters at the end of the string? 
Like, if for some reason I wanted to change NaCl to NaOH?

Any help and explanations would be really appreciated.

ETA:
I guess what I'm most confused on is how to make the program look at the last two letters in the string and compared them to OH.
I'm also not sure how to pass strings to functions.

Comment: It means that if your string is `"NaOH\n"` it will be true. To find whether substring `"OH"` is in the string you can use `char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 )` function. **For example**, `strstr("NaOH", "OH");`: if it returns 2 (in this case) then it is TRUE, but if NULL is returned that means there is no such substring in the string.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy - why isn't that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String** is a sequence of characters that ends with special *null*-terminated character `'\0'`. If there is no `\0`, functions that work with string won't stop until the `\0` symbol is found. This character may happen in any place after the end of *pseudo* string (I mean a string without `\0`) and only then stop.

The following example shows the necessity of this null-terminated character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "Hello!";

    printf("original string:\n%s\n\n", string);

    memset(string, '-', 5);
    printf("memset doesn't affect the last two symbols: '!' and '\\0':\n%s", string);

    memset(string, '-', 6);
    printf("\n\nmemset doesn't affect the last symbol: '\\0':\n%s\n\n", string);

    memset(string, '-', 7);
    printf("memset affects all symbols including null-terminated one:\n%s", string);

    return 0;
}

/* OUTPUT:
original string:
Hello!

memset doesn't affect the last two characters: '!' and '\0':
-----!

memset doesn't affect the last character: '\0':
------

memset affects all characters including null-terminated one:
-------@↓@
*/
```

---

**Substring** is a char sequence that is in a string. It may be less or equal to the string.
Suppose, `"NaOH"` is a string. Then substring may be: `"N"`, `"a"`, `"O"`, `"H"`, `"Na"`, `"aO"`, `"OH"`, `"NaO"`, `"aOH"`, `"NaOH"`. To find whether substring is in the string or not you can use `strstr` function. It's prototype is `char * strstr (       char * str1, const char * str2 );`.

This code shows this function's results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptrCh = NULL;

    ptrCh = strstr("hello", "h");
    printf("ptrCh: %p\n", ptrCh);
    printf("%s\n\n", ptrCh);

    ptrCh = strstr("hello", "z");
    printf("ptrCh: %p\n", ptrCh);
    printf("%s\n\n", ptrCh);

    return 0;
}

/* OUTPUT:
ptrCh: 00403024
hello     

ptrCh: 00000000
(null)
*/
```

As for the first printf, it prints characters beginning from the position of 'h' and when it reaches null-terminated character, which is next after 'o', it stops, exactly as in previous program.

---

To make your program **more interactive**, you can declare array and then a pointer to it. Array size must be enough to store the longest formula. Suppose, 100 will be enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[100] = {0};
    char *ptr = &buf[0];

    scanf("%s", ptr);

    // printf() gets a pointer as argument
    printf("%s\n", ptr);   

    // printf() gets also a pointer as argument. 
    // When you pass arrays name without index to a function,
    // you pass a pointer to array's first element.
    printf("%s", buf);     

    return 0;
}
```

---

And **as for *rewriting* letters** in the end of the string. Here is a small program that does it. Pay attention at comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[100] = {0};
    char formula[100] = {0};
    char compound[100] = {0};
    char *ptr = &buf[0];
    char *pFormula = &formula[0];
    char *pCompound = &compound[0];

    printf("Enter formula: ");
    scanf("%s", pFormula);
    printf("Enter chemical compound: ");
    scanf("%s", pCompound);

    // Copying the first chemical elements without the last
    // several that will be replaced by another elements.
    strncpy(ptr, pFormula, strlen(pFormula) - strlen(pCompound));
    // Adding new compound to the first elements.
    // Function also adds a null-terminated character to the end.
    strncat(ptr, pCompound, strlen(pCompound));

    printf("The new chemical compound is: ");
    printf("%s", ptr);

    return 0;
}

/* OUTPUT:
Enter formula: NaOH
Enter chemical compound: Cl
The new chemical compound is: NaCl
*/
```

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks for taking the time with all of this!

I do have a question though with the code for rewriting the letters.
For `strncpy(ptr, pFormula, strlen(pFormula) - strlen(pCompound));`
what does the `strlen(pFormula) - strlen(pCompound)` mean?

Comment: @PeachesTasteGood, nice to see this was useful for you. It is the number of all characters before the last ones that you want to change. For `"CH3CH2OH"`, `strlen(pFormula) - strlen(pCompound)` is 6 (CH3CH2) and you will copy them without the last 2 characters (OH). Then you concatenate you new compound, say (MgCl) to it. And as a result you'll get (CH3CH2MgCl). P.S. sorry for incorrect formula for the result -- frankly speaking, I don't like chemistry, though understand that it's very important branch of physical science.

Answer (score 1):

In C, we use null-terminated strings. That is the "invisible", 0 value. Not ASCII "0", but the zero value, like 8-bit 0x00. You can represent it in literal text with '\0' or "\0" or unquoted 0, however, in a literal string it is redundant because most functions like strcmp() or strstr() or strcat() all expect and work with null terminated strings. Null char is the stops sign for the C standard string functions.

One easy way to implement this with C library calls is to test for existence of the substring and then test that substring's length, which verify it is at end of string.

Assume buf is some big string buffer, `char buf[1024]` and `char *temp` is a temporary variable.

1. `temp = strstr(buf, "OH")` returns the pointer to "OH" if exists in buf at any offset.
2. `strlen(temp)`   Get length of temp, if at end of string, it will be 2 (doesn't include null terminator), so if the original string is "OHIO" or "SOHO" it wont match because it'll be 4 and 3 respectively.

The above is the core of the code, not the full robust implementation. You need to check for valid return values, etc.

```
char buf[1024];
char *temp;

strcpy(buf, "NaOH");

if((temp = strstr(buf, "OH")) != 0)
{
      // At this point we know temp points to something that starts with "OH"
      // Now see if it is at the end of the string
      if(strlen(temp) == 2)
            return true;          // For C99 include stdbool.h

      return false;
}
```

You could get obscure, and check for the null terminator directly, will be a smidge quicker. This code is safe as long as it is inside the if() for strstr(), otherwise never do this if you don't know a string is a least N characters long.

```
      if(temp[2] == '\0')
            return true;          // For C99 include stdbool.h
```

As far as appending to a string, read the docs on `strcat`. Keep in mind with strcat, you must have enough space already in the buffer you are appending into. It isn't like C++ std::string or Java/C# string where those will dynamically resize as needed. In C, you get to do all of that yourself.